# Why does voronoi texture switch use intensity coloring when ramped?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I am using a voronoi texture set to *position* coloring to drive a displacement modifier.  But I want to control the interpolation of the texture with a color ramp.  However when I go to the texture panel and check *ramp* the effect of the displacement modifier seems to switch to *intensity* coloring, even though the texture is still set to *position*.  **Why does it do this and how can I ramp a *position* voronoi texture?**

Here is the texture setup with no ramp, working as expected:
[image]

Here is the texture setup when I check ramp, the displacement now seems to be using *intensity*:
[image]

Also notice that the preview has gone blank, I have no idea why.

This is the kind of result I would like to achive:
[image]
This was made using the experimental cycles true displacement option, which is not an option for my final application.

Comment: When you set it to ramp one color is assigned to the center of the cell and gradually changed to the second color towards the edges. Im not sure why the preview is black though.

Comment: @Denis  That's if you have the coloring set to *intensity*, my point is that I have it set to *position* and it behaves like *intensity* when ramped.  I want something like if I put a *cells* voronoi texture through a color ramp in the cycles node editor.

Comment: I didn read your question properly, but I dont see how it can use ramp with position since position is using random values for each cell.

Comment: Probably using Constant Interpolation in texture settings may help you (sort of). It's not making the same result however: [no ramp](http://i.imgur.com/BJhD5gs.jpg), [with ramp](http://i.imgur.com/pQcnmsP.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

The ramp color dominates the Voronoi [position] as we have witnessed.

Design or Defect? Why? Perhaps the Blender Foundation can be asked.

The Blender Render texture settings can desaturate the position Voronoi colors to gray.
Once a gray is achieved the Blender Render can change colors based on a mapping space such as UV with a ramp.

The texture settings ramp can NOT change a color randomly based on a previous color, that information is not present.  That is a feature of the node systems.

The visual similarity of the color ramp in the Cycles Material Nodes and the Blender internal material/texture ramp is deceiving.  The Cycles node color ramp produces a color based on an input.  The Blender internal Material/Node color ramp specifies a color in a texture coordinate space which can be used to blend.

You wrote

[ I want something like if I put a cells Voronoi texture through a color ramp in the cycles node editor].  The texture settings of the material/texture without nodes cannot do this.

Perhaps we are using Cycles nodes so much we forget the old lesser capabilities of Blender Internal Material Textures.

It appears we are looking for a feature in the wrong place.

The node system of Blender Render can recolor a Voronoi texture based purely on color.

The node system of Cycles Render can recolor a Voronoi texture based purely on color.

Of course stating the some feature is not present in some area of Blender is a dangerous act.